# how to replace charactesr in string in React js Component ? i want to replace all '<' with blank spaces

Tags: reactjs

this is a  component where i want to implement this

```
export default function SingleBook () {    
     return (
     <div>
    // iam getting value in this where '<' is to be replace by ' '
                    <ListItemText primary={SingleBook.avg_rating.value} />
                   </div>
)
             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
SingleBook.avg_rating.value.replaceAll("<"," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'st<ing'.replaceAll('<',' ');

Answer (score 0):

The parts inside the curly braces in JSX is interpreted as normal JavaScript.

Therefore you can use all the ordinary JavaScript functions there, such as [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) or [String.prototype.replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)